# Flexslider - Updating Images via ng-repeat - Incorrect Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, flexslider

I have a page with image scrolling and I'm using Flexslider to do that.

Now the images are based on date sorting - So I click on last 7 days - it displays me last 7 day images (data is sent and received via AngularJS).

Now. The data returned as JSON is received is - Okay.

The problem is when data is returned and updated in the view via FlexSlider - The Flexslider is updated with the new data but the width of the flexslider remains according to the maximum elements that were previously present.

Why is that? Could somebody help?

```
<div class="recent_uploads mar_btm" ng-controller="recentuploadsController">
                        <div class="mar_btm titl_img"><h6>Recent Uploads</h6><!--<img alt="recent uploads" src="<?php echo base_url();?>public/image/net03.png">--></div>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="search.text" class="community-searching hide">
                        <button ng-click="clearSearch()" class="hide">clear</button>
                        <div class="rec_uplist_cont">
                            <div class="rec_uplist_slider">
                            <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                                <ul class="slides" style="width: 800%; transition-duration: 0.6s; transform: translate3d(-240px, 0px, 0px);">
                                        <div class="recnt_info" ng-if="recentupload!=null"><p> No Data Found</p></div>

                                        <li id="apptest" style="width: 226px; float: left; display: block;" class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="recentupload in recentuploads | filter:search.text">
                                        <div class="rec_uplist" >
             <div class="recnt_info">{{recentupload.user}} <span class="timeago" title="{{recentupload.time}}">{{recentupload.time}}</span></div>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_video"><img width="226" ng-click="showvideo(recentupload.id)" height="127" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{recentupload.embededCode}}/0.jpg" /></a>

                                            <a href="#" ng-click="showvideo(recentupload.id)" >{{recentupload.vtitle}}</a>
                                        </div>
                                        </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"><li><a class="">1</a></li><li><a class="flex-active">2</a></li></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a></li><li><a href="#" class="flex-prev">Previous</a></li></ul></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to detach or remove `flexslider` from `DOM` and after that initialize for the new gallery.

More info on how to remove `flexslider` [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213913/how-to-destroy-remove-unbind-a-flexslider)